# JQuery Ajax with multiple return values from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, webmethod

How can I return multiple values from JQuery.Ajax() in the success function ?

I tried it:

```
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "default.aspx/myFunction",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#myDiv").html(msg.a[0]);
                    $("#myDiv2").html(msg.a[1]);
                }
            });
```

And here my ASP.NET page:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function myFunction() As Array

     Dim a() As String
     a(0) = "value 1"
     a(1) = "value 2"

     Return a

End Function
```

It works just in unique return string, but array doesn't work :(

Comment: Is your WebMethod actually returning a json result?  Based on the code you posted, I don't think it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change it to `msg.d[0]`.

Wirting `msg.a` is completely wrong; the method's return value has nothing to do with a variable name.

However, for security reasons, ASP.Net wraps the JSON object in a `d` property, so you need to write `msg.d` to access the array.

Answer (score 1):

For Myself I used response.d to return the full array formatted in Comma's ex.[1,2,3]. To receive an individual, it's the same as the above (response.d[0]). The values were returned to AJAX as List(Of Strings) using a WebMethod.

```
                var Str = {};
                Str.StrVal = 'Test1';
                Str.StrVal2 = 'Test2';
                Str.StrVal3 = 'Test3';
                Str.StrVal4 = 'Test4';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "VB.aspx/GetString",
                    data: '{Str: ' + JSON.stringify(Str) + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("User has been added successfully." + response.d);
                        //window.location.reload();
                        //window.data("kendoWindow").close();
                        Str.StrVal = response.d[0]//response.d
                        //AddTab(response.d)
                        GetTabs(Str.StrVal)
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d)
                    }
                });
```

Here is the Web Method, Sorry for the brief Variable Description's. Just a sample.

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetString(Str As SendString) As List(Of String)
    Dim a As New List(Of String)
    a.Add("1")
    a.Add("2")
    Return a
End Function
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution!

I just use `msg.d[0]` instead `msg.a[0]`